# Which tense I do have to use if a main clause is in past simple tense and a subordinate clause is linked by the word before?

Tags: sequence-of-tenses

I have the following situation:

1. at first, I wrote a comment;
2. them Martin wrote a comment
3. then, after some time, I've seen the Martin's comment.

So would it be correct to describe this situation with one sentence so?

> My comment was written before I've seen the Martin's comment.

Comment: It should be "seen Martin's comment" not "seen the Martin's comment".

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["past simple tense + before + past perfect tense" pattern](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/47478/past-simple-tense-before-past-perfect-tense-pattern)

Comment: No, your suggested sentence is *not* syntactically valid. The second verb can't be *Present* Perfect. If you want to use a Perfect form, it must be *Past* Perfect: *...before I **had seen** his comment*. Note that *...before I **saw** his comment* is fine, as is *...before **seeing** his comment*, so there's no need to use a Perfect verb form at all.

Comment: @StuartF: That linked question addresses the difference between *My comment **was** written before I **had seen** the comment* and *My comment **had been** written before I **saw** the comment*, which doesn't seem directly relevant here,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OP's suggested sentence is *not* syntactically valid. The second verb can't be Present Perfect.

If you want to use a Perfect form, it must be Past Perfect...

> *My comment **was written**...*
> *...before **I had seen** his comment.*

Note that both these alternatives are fine, so there's actually no need to use a Perfect verb form at all....

> *...before **I saw** his comment.*
> *...before **seeing** his comment.*